# Shooting method -- why is NDSolve giving me an error message?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, warning-messages

I am currently trying to write a code to implement the so-called [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) (I've given a brief description of it below, for those unfamiliar) for second order ODE's in the form

$${\mathrm{d}^2y\over\mathrm{d}t^2} = f\left(t,y,{\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}t}\right),$$

which have given boundary conditions at $y(t_0) = y_0$ and $y(t_1) = y_1$ for $t_0 < t_1$.

> Notice that we do not know $y'(t_0) = v_0$, so we
>   make a "guess" at its value and see if it satisfies the second
>   boundary condition. Hence we are "shooting" an arrow (our initial
>   guess for velocity) and seeing if it hits the "target" (our second boundary
>   condition.) If it doesn't, we adjust our aim (our initial guess) and
>   try again."
>
> We have a function, $y(t)$ given by the equation of motion, with a
>   constant initial velocity $v_0$, and a different function $y_\text{shot}(t)$ which describes the trajectory of the same
>   particle in a different situation (i.e. for different $v_0$.) Therefore, $y_\text{end}(t)$ describes the point
>   at which $y(t_1)$ and $y_\text{shot}(t_1,v_0)$ have the same value at the same time, $t_1$. So, if we can find the point where both equations have the same height at the same time, we can find the initial velocity of both equations.

### *Mathematica* code

My code is as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

yShot[v0_, t0_, t1_, y0_, y1_] := 
  NDSolve[{y''[t] == f[t, y[t], y'[t]], y[t0] == y0, y'[t0] == v0}, 
   y, {t, t0, t1}];

(*Define function*)
f[t_, y_, v_] = -9.81 - 0.1 v;

(*Boundary conditions*)
t0 = 0;
t1 = 1;
y0 = 0;
y1 = 20;

v0guess = 30;

yend[v0_] := y[t1] /. yShot[v0, t0, t1, y0, y1][[1]]

Show[
 Plot[yend[v0], {v0, 0, v0guess}],
 Plot[y1, {v0, 0, v0guess}]
 ]

FindRoot[yend[v0] - y1 == 0, {v0, v0guess - 10, v0guess}]
```

which produces a grah showing the intersection of the two functions, as expected, and the following error message from both `NDSolve` and `FindRoot`:

> ```
> NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition v0 is not a number or a rectangular
> array of numbers. >>
> ```

$$\vdots$$

> ```
> ReplaceAll::reps: {y''[t]==-9.81-0.1 y'[t],y[0]==0,y'[0]==v0} is
> neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so
> cannot be used for replacing. >>
> ```

$$\vdots$$

> ```
> FindRoot::nlnum: "The function value of... is not a list of numbers
> with dimensions {1} at {v0} = {0.`}. >>
> ```

Can anyone see why this error message is being produced? It only seems to become a problem when `FindRoot` is involved.

Comment: BTW: `ParametricNDSolve[]` would be a better choice for implementing shooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate. You need to tell your functions that the arguments are numeric.

[image]